# User input as frequency with simpleTones.js

Tags: javascript, html, frequency

I would like to be able to take a user inputted number:

```
<input type = "number" id = "bets" min = "0" max = "42" value = "6">
```

and use it as the frequency for the function playTone() using simpleTones.js, as shown below.

```
var bets = document.getElementById("bets"); 
playTone(bets.value, "sine", 6)
```

So far I have not succeeded and am not sure whether that is possible. I'm wondering if there might be a way to do this.

Comment: Do you want to do this on any button click?

Comment: I have a button input that runs the function, I'd like the number input to define the frequency. Did that answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parseInt did solve it. The following works exactly as I intended:

```
function playBets() { 

    var bets = document.getElementById("bets"); 
    bets = parseInt(bets.value) + 440; 

    playTone(440, "sine", 6)
    playTone(parseInt(bets), "sine", 6)

}
```